# Get the value of a polynomial in two variables, by replacing only one variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

I'm using python 3.6.3 on Windows 7. I have the following code:

```
from sympy import *
x, a = symbols('x a')
q = 23*a + x**4 + 6*x**3 + x**2*(a + 14) + x*(8*a + 14) + 1
```

I wanted to get the value of q for x = 3, and I did:

```
q.evalf(subs={x:3})
```

I expected to get: `56*a + 412`, but all what I get is:

```
23.0*a + x**4 + 6.0*x**3 + x**2*(a + 14.0) + x*(8.0*a + 14.0) + 1
```

I haven't found anything in the documentation about getting the value of
an expression, by replacing only one variable.
How can I get the value of `q` for `x = 3`?

Comment: You can always do `q.subs({x:3})`, but I'm not sure why it didn't work with `evalf`

Comment: @ForceBru Thanks. Actually you answered my question. Where can I find about the subs method?

Comment: @LuoKaisa If you are using IPython, you can type `help(basic.Basic.subs)`. Or you just can go to [github](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/dc0d6cb29b90c3195fcffd4f6f066e4278122c81/sympy/core/basic.py#L807).

Comment: @LuoKaisa, in the docs online or simply `help(q.subs)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get the value using `evalf` and incomplete dictionary of variables.
As @ForceBru mentioned in comments, you can use Substitution function [`subs()`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/basic_operations.html#substitution).

---

There are sources when one can explore `evalf`: [github](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/core/evalf.py) or [sympy.core.evalf](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/_modules/sympy/core/evalf.html).

As one can see (when `verbose` option is `True`) the `evalf` performs calculation as a sequence of "atomic operations":

```
q.evalf(subs={x:3}, verbose=True)    
### input x
### output 3.0
### raw ((0, 3, 0, 2), None, 74, None)

### input x**4
### output 81.0
### raw ((0, 81, 0, 7), None, 67, None)
```

When `evalf` approaches `a` for the last time (it tries two times), `KeyError` is raised, and the expression is evaluated using [next lines](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/dc0d6cb29b90c3195fcffd4f6f066e4278122c81/sympy/core/evalf.py#L1311):

```
if 'subs' in options:
    x = x.subs(evalf_subs(prec, options['subs']))
xe = x._eval_evalf(prec)
re, im = xe.as_real_imag()
```

The `x` ends up as `a`, but result of evaluation `x._eval_evalf(prec)` is `None`. Since `xe` is `None`, the last mentioned line raises `NotImplementedError`.

This exception is handled in [`class EvalfMixin`](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/dc0d6cb29b90c3195fcffd4f6f066e4278122c81/sympy/core/evalf.py#L1358) in the [next lines](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/dc0d6cb29b90c3195fcffd4f6f066e4278122c81/sympy/core/evalf.py#L1446) where the input is returned:

```
except NotImplementedError:
    # Probably contains symbols or unknown functions
    return v
```

PS. I noticed too late that I answered comment of @ForceBru, strictly speaking. Let it stay as is.